# how can i get testone inside array value repeat list tag

Tags: angularjs

how can i get  testone  inside array value repeat  list tag

```
$scope.abc = [
    {
        testone: "x", 
        model: ['a', 'b']
    }
    , {
        testone: "y", 
        model: ['c', 'd']
    }
]
```

template:

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select getmdl-select__fix-height">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample2" value="Belarus"  tabIndex="-1">
    <label for="sample2">
        <i class="mdl-icon-toggle__label material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
    </label>
    <label for="sample2" class="mdl-textfield__label">Country</label>
    <ul for="sample2" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">
        <li class="mdl-menu__item"  ng-repeat="a in repeat abc.testone">{{a[0]}}</li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will answer will help you.

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select getmdl-select__fix-height">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample2" value="Belarus"  tabIndex="-1">
    <label for="sample2">
        <i class="mdl-icon-toggle__label material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
    </label>
    <label for="sample2" class="mdl-textfield__label">Country</label>
    <ul for="sample2" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">
        <li class="mdl-menu__item"  data-ng-repeat="a in abc" >
            {{a.testone}}
        </li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```